# Update Avro Library in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source "http://ci-stickler.com"
gemspec :name => "ci_canonical"
gemspec :name => "ci_canonical-serialization"
gem "rspec", "~> 3.0"
gem "rake", "~> 10.0"
```

When I am running `bundle update`, it is not updating the `avro` for `ci_canonical-serialization`. What am I missing here ?

I have updated the gem to 1.8.1 and installed the gem. My `Gemfile.lock` is generating as:

```
[ciuser@ci_canonical]$ head -n25 Gemfile.lock 
PATH
  remote: .
    specs:
      ci_canonical (11.0.5)
         domain_model (~> 0.4)
         enumerated_type (~> 0.4)
         json (~> 1.6)
      ci_canonical-serialization (11.0.5)
         avro (~> 1.7)
         ci_canonical (= 11.0.5)
GEM
   remote: http://ci-stickler.com/
     specs:
       avro (1.8.1)
          multi_json
       diff-lcs (1.2.5)
       docile (1.1.5)
       domain_model (0.4.0)
       enumerated_type (0.4.1)
       json (1.8.3)
       multi_json (1.12.1)
```

I have followed some posts but they didn't help. I am also not clear what we are specifying in `Gemfile` as `gemspec`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out answer myself. We might have multiple gems inside a single repository(could be git repository) and for all the gems, we have a `.gemspec` file associated which shall in turn tells about the dependencies.

So in my case, I was not modifying the second .gemspec file. Modifying it helped in resolving the problem.